# Recurrence relation for B-spline polynomials

Tags: difference-equations, splines

I am trying to get the explicit polynomials of cardinal [B-splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline). So far I have this implementation (for cardial B-splines of degree 3 on the knots 0, 1, 2, 3):

```
t[j_] := If[0 <= j <= 3, j, 0]
Simplify[PiecewiseExpand[RecurrenceTable[{B[i, k, x] == (x - t[i])/k * B[i, k - 1, x] + (t[i + k + 1] - x)/k*B[i + 1, k - 1, x], B[i, 0, x] == If[t[i] < x < t[i+1], 1, 0]}, B[i, k, x], {k,3,3}]]]
```

However, it doesn't seem to work: Mathematica is not solving the recurrence relations. As a reference, this is what I expect (from the Wikipedia page):

\begin{align}
 B_1 &= x^2/2, & 0 &\le x < 1, \\
 B_2 &= (-2x^2 + 6x - 3)/2, & 1 &\le x < 2, \\
 B_3 &= (3 - x)^2/2, & 2 &\le x < 3.
\end{align}

Where is my mistake here?

Edit:
Based on the comments from @thorimur, this does the trick

```
t[j_] := If[0 <= j <= 3, j, 0]
P[x_] := Simplify[PiecewiseExpand[RecurrenceTable[{B[i, k, x] == (x - t[i])/k * B[i, k-1, x]+(t[i+k+1]-x)/k*B[i+1, k-1, x], B[i, 0, x] == If[t[i] <= x < t[i+1], 1, 0]}, B[i, k, x], {k, 1, 2}, {i, 0, 3}]]]
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `RecurrenceTable`, but one thing I notice is that you don't iterate over `i`, yet expect an expression that doesn't include it. This suggests to me that something like `{i, 3, 3}` (or whatever makes sense here) should be included as an extra argument to `RecurrenceTable`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But even if I assign the expression with $P[x_,i_]:=Simplify[...]$ and then call $P[x,1]$ I am still getting expressions that depend on the previous recurrence call

Comment: Well, it seems like `B` depends recurrently on `i`, so `RecurrenceTable` needs to take the recurrence based on `i` into account so it can solve for it. Otherwise it views evaluations of `B` that involve different values of `i` as totally unrelated and not part of the recurrences it's solving. So instead of assigning it, you need something like `RecurrenceTable[eqns, B[i,k,x], {k, 3, 3}, {i, 1, 1}]`. (Note that you specifically need to *not* bind `i` in `P`.)

Comment: Also, note that you might instead need something like `RecurrenceTable[eqns, B[i,k,x], {k, 1, 3}, {i, 1, 3}][[k0, i0]]`, since i think `RecurrenceTable` needs to take into account values across a range to work...maybe.

Comment: Not sure I'll have time to look into this more but looking at the wikipedia page I also notice you might have a transcription error: it should maybe be `t[i] <= x < t[i + 1]`. Also, is the denominator of `k` correct?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the catch, you are right, there was a transcription error

Comment: It seems to work now (you can post it as an answer if you want the points from accepting the answer). The only thing I don't quiet know how to do is how to extract only the last equations from the last iteration of $k$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define cardinal B splines with a recursive definition. But you must take care that the integration variables remain localized. Further, memoization will help to speed up the calculation:

```
Clear[f]
f[0] = If[0 <= # <= 1, 1, 0] &;
f[n_] := f[n] = 
  Module[{ff}, 
   With[{ff = f[n - 1]}, 
    Evaluate[Integrate[ff[# - s] f[0][s], {s, 0, n + 1}]] &]]
```

Now, e.g.:

```
f[2][t]
```

[image]

Or:

```
Plot[{f[0][t], f[1][t], f[2][t], f[3][t]}, {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]